# How is this intersection of sets open?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

If $U$ is open in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and $A$ is any subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then $U \cap A$ is open in $A$.

I have re-expressed $U$ as an arbitrary union of open neighborhoods of the elements of $U$ and can reason how this intersection is open in $U$, but not how it is open in $A$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "open in $A$" mean?

Comment: Isn't it that "open in $A$" is **defined** as being the intersection of an open set and $A$? So nothing to prove here. Or you give us another definition of "open in $A$".

Comment: Take a look at the [subspace topology article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).

Answer (score 0):

Note that an open ball in A is by definition the intersection of an open ball in C and A.

Since U is a union of open balls in C, the intersection of U and A is a union of open balls in A, hence it is open in A.